# Gmail app send email with multiple attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to learn tosend bulk google mails with attachments using a spreadsheet.
In a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12yA7CVvZnwqC7qHz0yiR4N58Y9MHXUD5-b4EwZzS9XE/edit?usp=sharing), i have put the email address, the content template, and the attachments urls.

Here is what I found as code that I tried to use for my purpose :

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = 5; 
  var blobs = [];

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[2];  // 3rd column
    var subject = "Attachments";       
    var message = row[4];       // 5th column
    var attachments = row[3];     // Fourth column
    var emailSent = row[0];     // 1st column
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  

      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, attachments);

      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 1).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried lunching it, the email was sent but without attachments.
Please help me.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not stating what attachments to send. I see your calling something within the spreadsheet but not the attachment.

Try using something like this

```
 var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('attacheddoc.pdf');
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    attachments: [file.next().getAs(attacheddoc.PDF)],
    name: 'Attached Documents'
  }
```

So your code should look like

```
    var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

    function sendEmails() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 2;  
      var numRows = 5; 
      var blobs = [];

      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)

      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[2];  // 3rd column
        var subject = "Attachments";       
        var message = row[4];       // 5th column
        var attachments = row[3];     // Fourth column
        var emailSent = row[0];     // 1st column
        if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  

         var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(attachments.pdf');
  if (file.hasNext()) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    attachments: [file.next().getAs(attachments+'.PDF')],
    name: 'Attached Documents'
  }
        }
      }
    }
```

Hopefully that works for you. Would require some tinkering. However, I can't really do that for you without seeing the sheet. If it works +1?? :)

Comment: I have put the urls of docs in a column. How can i put those urls as the attachments?

Comment: If you have called those attachment's from your GDrive then add MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    attachments: [file.next().getAs(attacheddoc.PDF)],
    name: 'Attached Documents'

Comment: Changed my answer to help you